# Parametric Equations for Line(s) Tangent to a Sphere That Pass Through Point Outside of Sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Question asks for a the parametric equations for the set of all lines that pass through the point $(4,0,0)$ and are tangent to the curve:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2$$

My issue here is that I am not really sure how to approach the problem. The previous question asked for a similar thing but it wasn't as complicated as it was just the equation of a circle and not a sphere. Nevertheless, it was still the same point and it was still outside of the equation of the circle.

I am assuming there will be a general solution for this question since the question implies that there will be more than one line that passes through the point and is tangent to the sphere.

Am I supposed to utilize gradients to solve this? Or maybe the 3D tangent line equation? I am genuinely not sure how to approach this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you (i) embed affine space $R^3$ into 3-dimensional projective space by the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x:y:z:t)$ (ii) find E.A. Maxwell's old book on 3 dimensional projective geometry in a library or, even better, buy a copy through bookfinder (iii)  represent the line by 2 planes or by its Grassman Plucker coordinates, whichever works, best, and look at the conditions for tangency to $x^2+y^2+z^2-2t^2=0$ and passing through the point (4:0:0:1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise requires no calculus, just basic algebra, trigonometry and analytic geometry.

First let us look at the problem in a general setting with a sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin and a point $A(a,0,0)$ on the $x$-axis with $a>r$.

The diagram shows a the intersection of the sphere and the plane $z=0$ showing a tangent line to the sphere lying in that plane and intersecting at the point $B$ and intersecting the $y$-axis at point $P$. The coordinates of the various points can be found using basic principles such as ratios in similar triangles and the Pythagorean theorem. You should attempt to verify these for yourself.

[image: tangent to circle from exterior point]

The next diagram shows a circle in the plane $x=0$ containing a general point $P$ not necessarily on the $y$-axis as in the first figure, but lying on a circle centered at the origin and having radius $R=\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}$.

[[image: Circle on plane <span class=]$x=0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iou4A.png)

With this setup we can now express a general tangent line to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ as
$$ T=A(1-t)+ Pt$$

where $A=(a,0,0)$ and $P=\left(0,\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\sin\theta,\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\cos\theta\right)$

So the parametric equations, with parameters $t$ and $\theta$ are

\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&a(1-t)\\
y&=&\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}t\sin\theta\\
z&=&\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}t\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}

In your particular exercise, substitute $r=\sqrt{2}$ and $a=4$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.